# R as.yearqtr from zoo package: how to remove the blank

Tags: r, zoo

I'm using the function as.yearqtr() from the zoo package to convert a date like this:

2012-01-01

...and I would like to have it like this:

2012Q1

The problem with as.yearqtr is that it create a blank space between the year and the 'Q':

2012 Q1

How can I remove this blank?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change with `format`.  It would no longer have the `class` `yearqtr`, but would be just `character`

```
library(zoo)
format(as.yearqtr('2012-01-01'), '%YQ%q')
#[1] "2012Q1"
```

---

Or with `regex`

```
sub(" ", "", as.yearqtr('2012-01-01'))
```